# Как сделать, чтоб Facebook sdk брало значение meta-data из класса?

Tags: java, android

Я имплементировал facebook login и в манифесте теперь использую 2 значения для `meta-data` одно для релиза и одно для `debag`

```
<!--<meta-data-->
    <!--android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"-->
    <!--android:value="@string/facebook_app_id_release" />-->

<meta-data
    android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="@string/facebook_app_id_debag" />
```

в зависимости от ситуации одно держу закомментированным другое открытое так вот можно как то сделать, чтоб эти значения брались из кода?

Я бы тогда мог поставить флаг и не заморачиваться с переключением этих ключей

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

создаешь следующие файлы в директориях

```
src > release > res > values > strings.xml

src > debug > res > values > strings.xml
```

и в обоих файлах ставишь одинаковый string

```
<string name="facebook_app_id" translatable="false">yourId</string>
```

Comment: если что то непонятно могу подробнее объяснить

Comment: У меня нет папки `release` и `debug` ...

Comment: просто создайте их в папке src

Comment: а папку `res` которая изначально там есть так и оставить? Просто рядом с ней создать 2 новые ветки release и debug и в них сложить свои значения?

Comment: да, все верно, просто 2 новые ветки release и debug и в них сложить свои значения

Comment: я все так сделал, но манифест не видит это значение. Естественно при запуске получаю вот такую ошибку `Error:(73, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@string/facebook_app_id').`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48660/discussion-between---and-aleksey-timoshchenko).

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете менять необходимое значение в зависимости от build variants.

В AndroidManifest.xml пропишите:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
```

А в build.gradle:

```
release {
    ...
    resValue "string", "facebook_app_id", "value release"
}

debug {
    ...
    resValue "string", "facebook_app_id", "value debug"
}
```

Подобное можно реализовать также с помощью product flavors.

А еще есть такая штука, как [Manifest Merger](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html). Здесь она не нужна, но для общего понимания можете почитать, возможно, она понадобиться в дальнейшем.

Comment: данный метод хороший если мало таких стрингов, иначе захламляет весь код

Comment: @МаксимКузнецов, Я даю ответ по конкретному вопросу. Как можете видеть, в данном вопросе всего один ресурс.

Comment: я не критикую ваш ответ, он хороший, просто я прокоментиривал для понимания тем, кто будет использовать этот вариант.